# Missing access to node_modules/nan?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm attempting to install [this project](https://github.com/superflycss/cli) globally using `npm i -g`.

These are the steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/superflycss/cli
cd cli
npm i
npm i -g
```

The result is:

```
ole@mki:~/cli$ npm i -g
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to ~/cli/node_modules/nan
npm ERR! path /home/ole/cli/node_modules/nan
```

Thoughts?

If I try to `cd node_modules/nan` there is no such directory ... so that's one thing.  I'm not sure why it's trying to access that?

Comment: Have you tried to install it with `sudo`?

Comment: I have local home directory of global packages setup: http://www.competa.com/blog/how-to-run-npm-without-sudo/

Comment: https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

Comment: Have you tried `npm i -g @superflycss/cli`

Comment: That performs the install, but does not report the right version post install.  For example if I do `sfc --version` it reports `1.0.0` still, which is something I had installed earlier.  I also does not allow me to develop and test with a global install without first publishing to NPM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted all the contents of my local `~/.npm-packages` directory and reinstalled and now it works:

```
cd ~/.npm-packages
rm -fr *
cd ~/cli
npm i -g
```